# Php: Use a variable value to check class exists with ::class

Tags: php

I have the following:

```
if (class_exists($name::class)) {
    return new $name();
}
```

The class $name will be part of another namespace and this is in a factory method.

Php does not like this and throws error:

```
Fatal error: Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time
```

How can i get around this?

Comment: If `$name` holds the name of the class, how come you're trying to get the name via the `::class` constant? Isn't `class_exists($name)` all you need?

Comment: It is namespaced this is part of a factory method and the classes might exist across a couple of different namespaces

Comment: @MartyWallace Can you share the value of `$name` ?

Comment: If `$name` holds a string that represents a class name, then it must be the fully qualified name including namespace, otherwise it's worthless. So it's very unclear what `::class` is supposed to accomplish here.

Comment: It is correct behaviour, described in documentation [http://php.net/oop5.constants](http://php.net/oop5.constants) 'The special ::class constant are available as of PHP 5.5.0, and **allows for fully qualified class name resolution at compile**'. Possible workaround create static function in all handled classes: https://3v4l.org/CMmlW#output

Answer (score 1):

I remember that some time ago (maybe a week) I heard somewhere on the web, in a presentation about MVC or design patterns (I think), that such a construct as "::class" is not yet implemented in PHP. But maybe in PHP > 7. I'm not sure. Anyway: you don't need to use "::class".
But you need to pass a fully qualified name (FQN) to the class_exists. So it has to be an FQN-string. Example:

```
$classFQN = "\myNamespaceName\mySubNamespaceName1\mySubNamespaceName2\myClassName";
if (class_exists($classFQN)) {
return new $classFQN();
}
```

Notice the first "\" (back-slash). It makes a namespaced class name to a FULLY qualified name.
See "PSR-4: Autoloader" at http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: `::class` has existed for quite a while: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php. Otherwise good answer.

Comment: @deceze, you are right! 50 seconds ago I discovered it too on http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php. I come from the PHP max 5.4 planet :-) By the way, thank you for your appreciation!

Comment: One correction: string class names are *always* fully qualified and don't need to/should not start with a ``\``. You only start with a ``\`` to disambiguate between relative and FQ namespaces. Since strings are never treated as relative to the current namespace, it's superfluous.

Comment: @deceze Great explanation. I just read the docus again. Nothing found about it anymore. But I was curious. So I tested it: both, prefixed and unprefixed string namespaced class names resolve to the global space. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
function getClassInGlobal($name){
   if(isset($GLOBALS[$name])){
      if(is_object($GLOBALS[$name])){
         $obj = $GLOBALS[$name];
         return new $obj();
      }else{
         return false;
      };
   }else{
      return false;
   };
};

$Files = getClassInGlobal('myFilesClass');
if($Files){
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r(get_class_methods($Files));
   echo '</pre>';
};
```